# Using the SSML phoneme element

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, text-to-speech, ssml, phoneme

I am using Visual Basic.net Ultimate, and am developing a TTS application. May I please have some help with the phoneme element.

Here is the text that I wish to speak:

> As you release the tension in your shoulders and neck, take another deep breath in... and out.

Currently, the two words "breath in" seem to be running together and sound like "breath thin"
I would like to (via SSML) modify this statement so that the words sound like "breath in."

What would be the best way to do this via SSML? I am thinking that the phoneme element is the best way to do this.

Here is an example I have found to pronounce the word tomato:

```
<phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="təˈmeɪ.ɾoʊ"> tomato </phoneme>
```

The text between the ph section of the above code seems to be totally in a different language (:)). How do I use this language to spell out a word?

Answer (score 2):

This "totally different language" is the International Phonetic Alphabet. That's why on the same line it says: alphabet="ipa".

Different TTS systems use different phonetic representations of sounds, the IPA being one that some systems support.

I think for what you are doing a break tag would be more appropriate, as you are not looking to change the systems pronunciation of a word, but instead you wish for it to have a short pause between the two words.

If you specify which TTS engine you are using I can try to help more.